# api.meta.stackoverflow.com has state:normal - is this correct

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

i am not sure what the origin and exact meaning of the term 'linked_meta' is, but I would guess that it is a term created for area 51 meta sites and the implied meaning is clear.

Perhaps stack meta enjoys a different life than a lowly autogenerated linked_meta site, but i would submit that stack meta should be tagged as such in the interest of consistency and to facilitate programmatic handling of the /sites response, e.g. for sorting.

otherwise, we can simply ignore the site.state field and check the endpoint for '.meta.'

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StackOverflow Meta is different for the other Metas.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/)

This is one of the reasons that meta status is indicated with `state` and not just the `site_url`.

Valid states are:

- **normal** - a full member of the StackExchange network
- **open_beta** - a site, open to the public, who's continued existence depends on encouraging performance during the beta period
- **closed_beta** - a site which is closed to the public, only committers on its [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) proposal have write access
- **linked_meta** - a site paired with a "parent" site from which it inherits users, including reputation, and is *by definition* in the same operating state as its parent

meta.stackoverflow.com is a fully fledged site, with a distinct reputation system.

One other vagarity of parent->child meta sites is that a user's `user_id` on one will be the same on the other (though a child meta account may not exist for every user).  In the near-ish future account associations will start showing up for child meta sites in `/users/{id}/associated` as well.

Comment: understood. can we depend on the api.xxx -> api.meta.xxx convention?

Comment: @code poet - you can depend upon the *site_url* -> *meta.site_url* convention, so by extension yes I suppose api. -> api.meta. as well.

Comment: thanks. i am just looking for a discriminator so as to not go boom with/if a site shows up http://api.foometa.stackexchange.com -> http://api.meta.foometa.stackexchange.com - ok, so i made foometa up, there seem to be no words on the internet that end with meta, but you know as soon as I start descriminating on simply "meta." 5 'xxxmeta' sites with go prop>commit>beta in a matter of days.